# Use LIMIT and OFFSET with doctrines addSelect?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-query

I have following code:

```
->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("c.id, c.address, c.name")
                ->addSelect('(SELECT o.name FROM OOHMediaBundle:Offer o WHERE p.contractor_id = c.id ORDER BY o.created_at DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) as offer1')
                ->addSelect('(SELECT o.name FROM OOHMediaBundle:Offer o WHERE p.contractor_id = c.id ORDER BY o.created_at DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) as offer2')
```

It obviously do not work as LIMIT and OFFSET are not supported. Docs list solution for limiting main query. However I need to limit those subqueries and not main query.

So how to limit those subqueries?

Comment: For me this solution worked fine
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8180372/4361632

Comment: That would work, but it would add subqueries to my existing subqueries. How would it even look in dql?